# What does Jacob find that changes his mind?

Tags: plot-explanation, aftermath

In the latest Arnold Schwarzenegger vehicle [*Aftermath* (2017)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4581576/), Jacob attempts to overdose, and as he falls on his knees he sees some item under a bed.  it looks like a pen.  He picks up the item and then he changes his mind and attempts to vomit the pills out of his system.

What was this item, and why would it change his mind about his attempted suicide?